# Javascript DOM insertBefore

Tags: javascript, append

I'm trying to create a new textnode and insert it before the end of a div tag, what am I doing wrong? 
*edit*  Added HTML code for reference to JavaScript code, now I just have to add more text to complete the validation requirements on stackoverflow

```
<div id ="firstColumn">
        <div class="spin">
                    <a href="services.php"><img src="images/services.png"></a> 
        </div>

            <div id="firstColumnP">
                <p><a href="services.php"><span><strong>Services</strong></span></a><hr /><br /><br />
                Strategixis a multi talented agency offering bespoke web based systems and creative design solutions to businesses of all sizes and across all markets.
                We focus on adding business value 
                through the implementation of custom web based software solutions alongside great graphic design and application developments, including iPhone and Facebook apps
            </br>
            </br>
                  <p id="textArea"><!-- This is where I want to additional text--></p>


                  <span id="myBtn">Show more information</span>
                </p>
<p id="demo"></p>

            </div>
        </div><!--End of first column-->
    <div id ="secondColumn">
                        <div class="spin">
                    <a href="services.php"> <img src="images/about.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="secondColumnP"><p><a href="about.php"><span><strong>About us</strong></span></a><hr /><br /><br />
            Choose Strategixis and you are choosing an established web and online marketing agency with a team of highly experienced designers, 
            developers and marketers at your disposal. 
            From concept to completion, we will plan, design and develop your website, supporting you throughout the process and beyond to help you grow your business online.
        </p>
            </div>
    </div><!--End of second column-->



   window.onload = function latestNews(){
      var newPara = document.createElement("p");
      var add_news = document.createTextNode("The leatest news goes here");
      newPara.appendChild(add_news);
      var getSecond = document.getElementById("secondColumn");
      document.body.insertBefore(newPara, getSecond);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please repost your code with correct formatting? Use the code markup tool, not the quotation, so it won't be wrapped.

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean like that?

Comment: Is `secondColumn` a child of `<body>`?

Comment: Yes, I'll add the HTML code too

Comment: Tell us what's happening or should happen and what does not work etc.

Comment: It should create a new element <p> then add text then add before the second column, it tells me Node was not found.

Comment: It works here — http://jsfiddle.net/dsva5e73/ — the problem isn't with the code you've shared.

Comment: I'm confused then, when I run it on local drive it doesn't show up, I'm currently using Firefox